# How can make array in prolog?

Tags: arrays, prolog

I want to make an array in Prolog. How can do it? How can access the elements?

Comment: tnx, i know this link. and something about Lists in prolog but i want to learn something like array in c++ (or c) with a simple example. if you have it please share.  tnx again

Comment: AFAIK, it is impossible to make an array in prolog, but you can simulate it with a simple predicate "returning" i-th element of your list if you really need it.

Comment: List can use for 8-puzzle problem??

Comment: @MitchWheat dead links.

Comment: @ gsamaras: so go find active ones and post yourself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no 'array' in prolog. I mean, you cannot get an *indexed list*. All you have to do is access the list as somewhat like a *linked list*. You'll have to do it in a *recursive* way.

Comment: List can use for 8-puzzle problem??

Comment: -1. The standard Prolog way to have (possibly length-limited, possibly un-updatable) arrays is with `arg/3` predicate, which allows direct indexing. Bratko gives amazing code for the "8-puzzle" (which I take to mean 8-queens puzzle) using this technique, and the key there is that the value at a given index can **not** be changed after it was first set.

Answer (score 8):

The stadard Prolog way of having (possibly limited in length, non-mutable) arrays is with `arg/3` predicate:

```
11 ?- length(X,4), A =.. [g|X], arg(1,A,a).

X = [a, _G590, _G593, _G596]
A = g(a, _G590, _G593, _G596) 

Yes

12 ?- length(X,4), A =.. [g|X], arg(1,A,a), arg(3,A,c), arg(2,A,b), arg(1,A,d).

No
13 ?- length(X,4), A =.. [g|X], arg(1,A,a), arg(3,A,c), arg(2,A,b), arg(4,A,d).

X = [a, b, c, d]
A = g(a, b, c, d) 

Yes
```

Bratko (["Prolog programming for artificial intelligence"](http://books.google.co.il/books/about/Prolog_programming_for_artificial_intell.html?id=-15su78YRj8C&redir_esc=y)) has the code to solve the classic 8 queens problem using this feature.

Another way to emulate arrays in Prolog is to encode your list as a binary tree, for `O(log(n))` access time.

Comment: Some timing seems to show that arguments of a functor are still represented and accessed as a linked list internally. :(... is there a way around this?  I am implementing a language and this algorithmic inefficiency is unacceptable.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong number.  I was reading the result as the inference count.  Programming while drunk haha.  1 inference no matter the argument requested, beautiful.

Comment: I left them because I thought someone might benefit from knowing that the access time on arguments of a functor using `arg/3` is O(1).  Knowing there is a good abstraction is one thing, knowing the abstraction has the expected algorithmic efficiency is another. :)

Comment: Of interest: [Does SWI-Prolog have N+K-trees?](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/does-swi-prolog-have-n-k-trees/1310)

Comment: @GuyCoder that's a different problem though, a *resizable* array. btw cf. this [related data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashed_array_tree).

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a Prolog that has unlimited arity on terms, like SWI-Prolog, you can use [setarg/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=setarg/3) to emulate a vector.

Please read [the notes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setarg/3) that the project leader wrote on the argument.

I've never used arrays in Prolog, but answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519203/prolog-replace-an-element-in-a-list-at-a-specified-index/8544713#8544713) question, I tested for efficiency of the functionality. Actually works fairly well.

Comment: I think this is a much closer equivalent to arrays in Prolog than the accepted answer of linked lists.

Comment: not even `setarg` but a simple and standard **`arg`** will do - is much better actually - for an "8-puzzle problem". The key is that it's **not** updatable. (seen it in Bratko)

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate an array using a binary heap. Accessing and changing an element is in Theta(log(i)) where i is the index of the element, instead of Theta(1) for an array in say C.

```
:- module(arraysim, [insertAS/4,getAS/3]).
%------------------------------------------------------------------------    
%
% AUTHOR: Pierre
%
% USE OF A BINARY TREE TO STORE AND ACCESS ELEMENTS INDEXED FROM THE
% SET OF POSITIVE INTEGERS, I.E. SIMULATION OF SPARSE ARRAYS.
%
% Provide predicates:
% = =================
%
% insertAS(+Value,+Index,+Tree,-NewTree) to insert/rewrite Value at node
% of index Index in Tree to produce NewTree.
%
% getAS(-Value,+Index,+Tree): to get the Value stored in node of index
% Index in Tree. Value is nil if nothing has been stored in the node
% (including the case when the node was never created).
%
% User note:
% =========
%
% assume indexation starts at 1.
% The empty Tree is [].
%
% Data Structure:
% ==============
%
% The nodes of the binary tree are indexed using the indexing scheme
% employed to implement binary heaps using arrays. Thus, the indexes of
% elements in the tree are defined as follows:
%
% The index of the root of the tree is 1
% The index of a left child is twice the index of the parent node
% The index of a right child is twice the index of the parent node plus
% one.
%
% A tree is recursively represented as a triple:
% [Value,LeftTree,RightTree] where Value is the value associated with
% the root of the tree. if one of LeftTree or RightTree is empty this
% tree is represented as an empty list.
%
% However, if both left and right tree are empty the tree (a leaf node)
% is represented by the singleton list: [Value].
%
% Nodes that correspond to an index position whose associated value has
% not been set, but are used to access other nodes, are given the
% default value nil.
%
% Complexity:
% ==========
%
% Insertion (insertAS) and extraction (getAS) of the element at index i
% runs in Theta(log_2(i)) operations.
%
% The tree enables to store sparse arrays with at most a logarithmic (in
% index of element) storage cost per element.
%
% Example of execution:
% ====================
%
% 10 ?- insertAS(-5,5,[],T), insertAS(-2,2,T,T1),
% | insertAS(-21,21,T1,T2), getAS(V5,5,T2),
% | getAS(V2,2,T2),getAS(V10,10,T2),getAS(V21,21,T2).
% T = [nil, [nil, [], [-5]], []],
% T1 = [nil, [-2, [], [-5]], []],
% T2 = [nil, [-2, [], [-5, [nil, [], [-21]], []]], []],
% V5 = -5,
% V2 = -2,
% V10 = nil,
% V21 = -21.
%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% find_path(+Index,-Path)
%
% Given an index find the sequence (list), Path, of left/right moves
% from the root of the tree to reach the node of index Index.
%
%------------------------------------------------------------------------

find_path(Index,Path):-
    integer(Index),
    Index > 0,
    find_path2(Index,[],Path).

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%
% find_path2(+Index,+Acc,-Path)
%
% Use of an accumulator pair to ensure that the sequence is in the
% correct order (i.e. starting from root of tree).
%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------


find_path2(1,Path,Path):-!.
find_path2(Index,Path,ReturnedPath):-
    Parity is Index mod 2,
    ParentIndex is Index div 2,
(   Parity =:= 0
->  find_path2(ParentIndex,[left|Path],ReturnedPath)
;   find_path2(ParentIndex,[right|Path],ReturnedPath)
).

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%
% insertAS(+Value,+Index,+Tree,-NewTree)
%
% Insert Value at node of index Index in Tree to produce NewTree.
%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

insertAS(Value,Index,Tree,NewTree):-
    find_path(Index,Path),
    insert(Value,Path,Tree,NewTree),!.

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%
% insert(+Value,+Path,+Tree,-NewTree)
%
% Insert Value at position given by Path in Tree to produce
% NewTree.
%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

% insertion in empty tree
%
insert(Value,[],[],[Value]).
insert(Value,[left|P],[],[nil,Left,[]]):-
    insert(Value,P,[],Left).
insert(Value,[right|P],[],[nil,[],Right]):-
    insert(Value,P,[],Right).

% insertion at leaf node
%
insert(Value,[],[_],[Value]).
insert(Value,[left|P],[X],[X,Left,[]]):-
    insert(Value,P,[],Left).
insert(Value,[right|P],[X],[X,[],Right]):-
    insert(Value,P,[],Right).

% insertion in non-empty non-leaf tree
%
insert(Value,[],[_,Left,Right],[Value,Left,Right]).
insert(Value,[left|P],[X,Left,Right],[X,NewLeft,Right]):-
    insert(Value,P,Left,NewLeft).
insert(Value,[right|P],[X,Left,Right],[X,Left,NewRight]):-
    insert(Value,P,Right,NewRight).

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%
% getAS(-Value,+Index,+Tree)
%
% get the Value stored in node of index Index in Tree.
% Value is nil if nothing has been stored in the node
% (including the case when the node was never created).
%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

getAS(Value,Index,Tree):-
    find_path(Index,Path),
    get(Value,Path,Tree),!.

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
%
% get(-Value,Path,+Tree)
%
% get the Value stored in node with access path Path in Tree.
% Value is nil if nothing has been stored in the node
% (including the case when the node was never created).
%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------

get(nil,_,[]).
get(nil,[_|_],[_]).
get(Value,[],[Value]).
get(Value,[],[Value,_,_]).
get(Value,[left|P],[_,Left,_]):-
    get(Value,P,Left).
get(Value,[right|P],[_,_,Right]):-
    get(Value,P,Right).
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two articles on how to do it :

[Arrays in Prolog](https://myriad.website/arrays-in-prolog/)

[Arrays using OOP](https://myriad.website/arrays-in-prolog-and-oop/)

but the shortest answer :

```
ary1d_new(Size,Sym,Ary) :- 
  functor(Ary,a1,Size), 
  forall(arg(X,Ary,_), nb_setarg(X,Ary,Sym)).
ary1d_get(Pos,Ary,Val) :- arg(Pos,Ary,Val).
ary1d_set(Pos,Ary,Val) :- nb_setarg(Pos,Ary,Val).
```